# Python/Pandas: Use lookup DataFrame + function to replace specific/null values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have an incomplete dataset in a Pandas DataFrame such as:

```py
incData  = pd.DataFrame({'comp': ['A']*3 + ['B']*5 + ['C']*4,
                         'x': [1,2,3] + [1,2,3,4,5] + [1,2,3,4],
                         'y': [3,None,7] + [1,4,7,None,None] + [4,None,2,1]})
```

And also a DataFrame with fitting parameters that I could use to fill holes:

```py
fitTable = pd.DataFrame({'slope': [2,3,-1],
                         'intercept': [1,-2,5]},
                         index=['A','B','C'])
```

I would like to achieve the following using y=x*slope+intercept for the None entries only:

```py
   comp  x     y
0     A  1   3.0
1     A  2   5.0
2     A  3   7.0
3     B  1   1.0
4     B  2   4.0
5     B  3   7.0
6     B  4  10.0
7     B  5  13.0
8     C  1   4.0
9     C  2   3.0
10    C  3   2.0
11    C  4   1.0
```

One way I envisioned is by using join and drop:

```py
incData = incData.join(fitTable,on='comp')
incData.loc[incData['y'].isnull(),'y'] = incData[incData['y'].isnull()]['x']*\
                                         incData[incData['y'].isnull()]['slope']+\
                                         incData[incData['y'].isnull()]['intercept']
incData.drop(['slope','intercept'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However, that does not seem very efficient, because it adds and removes columns. It seems that I am making this too complicated, do I overlook a simple more direct solution? Something more like this non-functional code:

```py
incData.loc[incData['y'].isnull(),'y'] = incData[incData['y'].isnull()]['x']*\
                                         fitTable[incData[incData['y'].isnull()]['comp']]['slope']+\
                                         fitTable[incData[incData['y'].isnull()]['comp']]['intercept']
```

I am pretty new to Pandas, so I sometimes get a bit mixed up with the strict indexing rules...

Comment: The performance of the answers scales like this: apply < map < numpy < join. Script that I used to time: https://github.com/Z4uit/Stackoverflow-snippets/blob/master/StackOverflow%20question%2061108566 Feel free to comment on the timeit approach, it is the first time I used it

Comment: If the size of the data is increased, the picture changes completely, as suggested by @Ben.T: map < numpy < join << apply. See adjusted code here: https://github.com/Z4uit/Stackoverflow-snippets/blob/master/StackOverflow%20question%2061108566%20(x1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `map` on the column 'comp' once mask with null value in 'y' like:

```
mask = incData['y'].isna()
incData.loc[mask, 'y'] = incData.loc[mask, 'x']*\
                         incData.loc[mask,'comp'].map(fitTable['slope']) +\
                         incData.loc[mask,'comp'].map(fitTable['intercept'])
```

and your non-functional code, I guess it would be something like:

```
incData.loc[mask,'y'] = incData.loc[mask, 'x']*\
                        fitTable.loc[incData.loc[mask, 'comp'],'slope'].to_numpy()+\
                        fitTable.loc[incData.loc[mask, 'comp'],'intercept'].to_numpy()
```

Comment: I never saw the potential of the map function, but it has quite a performance as compared to converting it to bumpy first. I compared the two with timeit: 100 evals -> map: 0.373 s, bumpy 0.467 s. >> P.s. I really like the mask variable, it declutters much of the code, and it makes it run actually slightly faster than putting isna() everywhere

Comment: @Adriaan `apply` is faster in your test because you use a dataframe of 5ish missing rows. increase the size of missing rows, assuming your real data is bigger, and I bet apply won't be the fastest!

Comment: @Adriaan in your code for timing, add for example `incData = pd.concat([incData]*100)` for each method just after you create `incData` and you'll see that `apply` is not the fastest anymore

Comment: You are very right, I just multiplied all lists in incData with 1000 and the results are very different. Somehow map is still the fastest, any ideas on why it outperforms numpy?

Comment: using concat slows down the whole process, so multiplying the lists was a fairer comparison, I will update the code in the comment on my question

Comment: @Adriaan yes `concat` is not the best, it was an easy way to show that performance between methods depends on the size. Also if you have more different `comp` values, it may be different, etc... I just wanted to point out that performance test can be a bit tricky ;)

Comment: Either way, I will accept your answer and go with map, it is the least cluttered code, the performance is similar to join and I learned a new function! :)

Comment: @Adriaan and regarding the performance of the solution called `numpy`, it is actually more related to the performance of using `loc` than a full numpy solution :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
incData.loc[pd.isna(incData['y']), 'y'] = incData[pd.isna(incData['y'])].apply(lambda row: row['x']*fitTable.loc[row['comp'], 'slope']+fitTable.loc[row['comp'], 'intercept'], axis=1)

incData
comp  x     y
0     A  1   3.0
1     A  2   5.0
2     A  3   7.0
3     B  1   1.0
4     B  2   4.0
5     B  3   7.0
6     B  4  10.0
7     B  5  13.0
8     C  1   4.0
9     C  2   3.0
10    C  3   2.0
11    C  4   1.0
```

Comment: This is actually the fastest of all solutions posted here! This feels weird to me, since I read that apply is basically an efficient for loop. Why would it be faster than the vectorised approach proposed by @Ben.T? Is it because map also loops through the dataframe to replace the values?

Comment: Great! Yes map does almost the same thing as apply, they don't differ that much in performance

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is another option

```
# merge two dataframe together on comp
m = incData.merge(fitTable, left_on='comp', right_index=True)
# y = mx+b
m['y'] = m['x']*m['slope']+m['intercept']

   comp  x   y  slope  intercept
0     A  1   3      2          1
1     A  2   5      2          1
2     A  3   7      2          1
3     B  1   1      3         -2
4     B  2   4      3         -2
5     B  3   7      3         -2
6     B  4  10      3         -2
7     B  5  13      3         -2
8     C  1   4     -1          5
9     C  2   3     -1          5
10    C  3   2     -1          5
11    C  4   1     -1          5
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the join method I proposed, but I read that join is faster. Also, you still add the redundant slope and intercept columns. Finally, all values of y are replaced, while I only wanted to replace those with NaN/None/Null. Although not the case here, it is true that merge can offer better functionality than join.